# How to pass a string parameter to a component without using quotes?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the "tweak" to use/pass a string attribute to a component without using quotes:

I'm always "forced" to use simple quotes inside double quotes like this:

```
    ... [anyattribute]="'MyLabel'" ...
```

I want to use like this:

Using component:

```
<my-component [anyattribute]="MyLabel"></my-component>
```

component.ts:

```
export class MyComponent {
    
    @Input() anyattribute: string;
    
    constructor(){}
}
```

component.html:

```
<label> {{anyattribute}} </label>
```

I've seen some custom components receive parameters on input attributes without the use of double quotes. But don't know what I have to adjust.

Any help?

Comment: Just remove the square backets !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the square backets an use it like standard HTML !

```
<my-component anyattribute="MyLabel"></my-component>
```